# libspotify API: loading playlist container to get playlist metadata?

Tags: spotify

I loaded the playlist container and then got the pointers to each playlist, and from the playlist pointers (sp_playlist *) to get the name and URI of each playlist. But the result shows not all the playlist name and URI can be retrieved. What types of playlist metadata does playlist container provide?

Also, is playlist stored in local cache? Do I have to wait for the playlist to be loaded to the cache?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The playlist container contains no playlist metadata — only a list of playlist pointers. You need to wait for each playlist to load before its name is available. Also, be aware that the playlist container will have folder markers in there too, which don't have names at all. You can check that with `sp_playlistcontainer_playlist_type()`.

Playlists are indeed stored in the local cache, as long as you log out correctly and wait for the logout completion callback before terminating your process.

Comment: I don't understand - how to trigger the "load" of a playlist or how to load a playlist if playlist container is loaded and _sp_playlist *_ is available? Isn't it supposed to wait for the callbacks (either **metadata_updated** or **playlist_state_changed**) to check the "load"?  Same question for tracks - what triggers a track to be loaded? The only thing I know is to register their callbacks. Did I understand correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Once you have the `sp_playlist` object it starts loading on its own. Use the callbacks you mentioned to see when it loads. Same for `sp_track`.

Comment: I think I found the reason. If the local cache is empty, the procedure of loading playlists is: load container, add playlist, rename playlist. I thought the playlist callback "state changed" instead of "renamed" was called when a playlist is loaded. The API document is a bit confusing.

Comment: And I noticed, when "playlist_renamed" call back is called, the name is available, but playlist is still not loaded. That's weird, if playlist is not loaded, how can the name be retrieved.

Comment: And, I don't understand why the example "spshell" doesn't have to check if playlist is loaded or not before retrieving playlist name and works perfect. My code is exactly same to retrieve playlist name  but just doesn't work in the same way.

Comment: When something in libSpotify is loaded, it means it has *finished* loading. Since loading the entire track list of a playlist can take a long time, it doesn't make sense to hold the name back for that long.